# Is it possible to force OpenSSL to not generate SIGPIPE without global signal handler change?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, openssl

I write static library that that refers to static OpenSSL library. OpenSSL generates `SIGPIPE` sometimes and crashes program. I know that it is possible to use `signal` function to disable `SIGPIPE` globally. However, for static library such requirement is not elegant (unlike shared library where you can call `signal` in initialization function). Also the method that doesn't need global changes in program is much better, because who knows may be any other library requires `SIGPIPE` and will conflict with library that requires to ignore this signal. I think good practice is to change `BIO` only and nothing else.
OpenSSL uses sockets, and sockets `send` function contains good solution (`MSG_NOSIGNAL` flag). Is there any similar solution for OpenSSL? Is there any way to setup OpenSSL BIO in such a way that it will not generate `SIGPIPE` and not crash entire program?

Comment: Do not let a library change any process wide settings.

If you want provide functions allowing the programmer using the library to "switch off" and "switch on" `SIGPIPE's default behaviour, that is ending the program. 

Document the default behaviour of the library (and the "switch"-function if added) and you are done.

Comment: Your motivation is commendable but I've never seen a program that actually wanted SIGPIPE, rather than handling it itself via errno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> OpenSSL generates SIGPIPE sometimes and crashes program

I don't believe its OpenSSL; rather, its the operating system in response to the peer closing the SSL socket in a "dirty" manner.

Eric Rescorla touches upon it [An Introduction to OpenSSL Programming (Part I)](http://www.rtfm.com/openssl-examples/part1.pdf):

> When we send our `close_notify`, the other side may send a TCP RST
>   segment, in which case the program will catch a `SIGPIPE`. We install
>   a dummy `SIGPIPE` handler in `initialize_ctx()` to protect against
>   this problem.

I don't agree with "do nothing but document it". If RTFM was going to work, then it would have happened by now. Its *not* OK to crash the application and claim the answer is in the manual somewhere. You should do the right thing out of the box and document how to change the behavior.

Perhaps you should install the `SIGPIPE` handler *if* the program does not install one itself. If the program installs one, then you maybe should provide a code path back into your library to notify you when it occurs (if you need it).

You can test for an existing `SIGPIPE` handler (and install one if not present) with something like the following. I use similar in Debug builds to install a `SIGTRAP` handler so my asserts don't crash the program I am debugging. (Complete coverage with asserts creates self debugging code. I rarely spend any time under a debugger because the code tells me where the problems are).

```
struct SigPipeHandler
{
  SigPipeHandler()
  {
    // http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/sigaction.html
    struct sigaction old_handler, new_handler={ };

    do
      {
        int ret = 0;

        ret = sigaction (SIGPIPE, NULL, &old_handler);
        if (ret != 0) break; // Failed

        // Don't step on another's handler
        if (old_handler.sa_handler != NULL) break;

        // Set up the structure to specify the null action.
        new_handler.sa_handler = &SigPipeHandler::NullSigPipeHandler;
        new_handler.sa_flags = 0;

        ret = sigemptyset (&new_handler.sa_mask);
        if (ret != 0) break; // Failed

        // Install it
        ret = sigaction (SIGPIPE, &new_handler, NULL);
        if (ret != 0) break; // Failed

      } while(0);
  }

  static void NullSigPipeHandler(int /*unused*/) { }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

OpenSSL does not generate `SIGPIPE` by itself. But, OpenSSL uses sockets and if you write to a socket where the other end is closed already a `SIGPIPE` will be generated. If you don't want this you have to handle `SIGPIPE` (like setting it to `SIG_IGN`). This will then cause the write to return `EPIPE` error.

Because this behavior is not specific to OpenSSL but common to all sockets and because this is a global setting you should not change it in your library. You might mention it in the documentation, but this should be only necessary if you expect a user which is not familiar with the standard behavior of sockets.

Comment: Oh, that's cool. I did not know `SIG_IGN` would result in `EPIPE`.

Comment: This information is hidden in the write(2) manpage: "EPIPE - fd is connected to a pipe or socket whose reading end is closed.  When this happens the writing process will also receive a SIGPIPE signal.  (Thus, the write return value is seen only if the program catches, blocks or ignores this signal.)"

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you setup SSL over socket. If you are using `SSL_set_fd`, you can prevent generation of SIG_PIPE with `setsocketopt` and `SO_NOSIGPIPE`.

Comment: `SO_NOSIGPIPE` is not supported by Linux I think.